# "Womit und mit was": Tautologie oder Bedeutungsunterschied?

Tags: pronominal-adverb, rhetoric

> **Womit und mit was** hat der Buchverleger zu rechnen, der seinen Beruf ernst nimmt und Tabus nicht akzeptiert? (*Die Zeit*, 24.6.1966, gefunden via [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpora/public))

Präpositionaladverbien wie *womit* werden allgemein als Ersatzformen für Verbindungen von Präposition und *was* gesehen; der Ersatz gilt teilweise in der Standardsprache als obligatorisch.

Welche Funktion hat *mit was* in obigem Beispiel? Handelt es sich nur um ein Synonym zu *womit*, so daß eine Tautologie vorläge, oder geht es um verschiedene Arten von Dingen, mit denen ein Buchverleger zu rechnen hat?

Edit: Der ganze Artikel kann, wenn man bereit ist, eine E-Mail-Adresse zu opfern, unter *[Droht eine Diktatur der Anständigkeit?](https://www.zeit.de/1966/26/droht-eine-diktatur-der-anstaendigkeit) Zensurpraxis und Zensurbestrebungen in der Bundesrepublik* gelesen werden. Es geht um die Indizierung von Büchern.

Comment: Ich betrachte die Begriffe als synonym, stelle aber fest fest, dass *rechnen* hier mehrdeutig ist: a) Auf was muss sich der Verleger einstellen? b) Rentabilität,  Rückstellungen und weitere Berechnungen.  Vielleicht sollte diese Mehrdeutigkeit adressiert werden? Unabhängig davon empfinde ich die Formulierung als nicht besonders geglückt.

Comment: Ergibt sich irgendein Hinweis aus dem originalen Artikeltext?

Answer (score 2):

Meines Erachtens soll das deutlich machen, dass es **sowohl** um das Mittel **als auch** um die Umstände geht. Zwar kann man gleichermaßen mittels *womit* und *mit was* nach beiden Dingen fragen, man wird aber wohl kaum zweimal nach dem Mittel oder zweimal nach den Umständen fragen.